# How can I reserve RAM for my Python script?

Tags: python, memory, sharing

I am sharing a server at my university with other students. The server's RAM is way too small, and I am facing a situation that I can almost never run my programs due to memory error. The script is running in chunks, but if there is a server overload, I am screwed.

Do you have any advice? Perhaps there is a way to reserve RAM for my Python process. I know it's quite non-trivial to release memory from python. Perhaps I can write a script, that is going to allocate the memory to my Python, when it becomes free. After, I have enough, perhaps I can use gc.collect(), but somehow ensure that the memory stays on my machine for purposes of running the scripts?

Thanks!

Edit: I am providing step where the script brakes. I am saving the data in chunks. I was able to run it yesterday! I know I can increase the number of chunks, but today I was pulling less than 5gb of ram when this happened.

```
    for hour in np.arange(logins.hours.min(),logins.hours.max()+1):
        start_time = time.time()
        dict_choices=process_day(hour,dict_choices).copy()
        df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_choices,orient='index') 
        df['hour']=hour
        rezovi[i]=df
        i=i+1
        print("Handled hour {} in year {} in %s seconds (iteration {}) ---".format(-hour/mini,year,i) % round((time.time() - start_time),2))

        if ((i % 100)==0):
               rezultat=pd.concat([df for df in rezovi.values()], ignore_index=False).reset_index()
               keep=list(rezultat.columns.values[0:7])
               keep.append('hour')
               rezultat=rezultat[keep]
               rezultat=convert_types(rezultat,print_info=True)
               rezultat.to_csv('save/2018/chunk'+str(hour)+'.csv')
               del rezovi,rezultat,keep,df
               gc.collect()
               rezovi={}
               i=0
```

Comment: If the server doesn't give you the memory, there's nothing really within the script itself to make it do so. Or are you saying, while your script is running, randomly at runtime other processes are being run that cause the server to run out of memory; and you are trying to hog all the memory yourself from the start to not let other processes get any…?

Comment: Fix your code so it *doesn't* use memory it doesn't need. What you see as an inconvenience in a university environment is a *huge* problem on high traffic web servers that have to share the same memory among many concurrent requests. For example, instead of loading a text file in memory, load it line by line or chunk by chunk. Reuse the same buffer instead of allocating new ones every time.

Comment: The best you can do here is optimise your code to cut down on memory usage. Consider using `del` to delete objects that you no longer need. And, as Panagiotis said, load data into memory as small chunks, instead of all at once.

Comment: Usually you wouldn't manage this from Python. The usual approach to this sort of problem is to setup a job queue on the server. There is a myriad of systems out there, allowing you to define priorities, resource limits, etc. to make sure the server usage is fair and jobs don't compete with each other.

Comment: Do you know which part of your Python script is consuming all this memory? Please show it by editing your question.

Comment: its actually pretty cheap to rent time on an AWS (or similar) and run your script there. If you NEED to get it done but can't on your server, i'd do that.

Comment: @deceze Exactly. I am trying to hog a certain memory formyself, to ensure it will operate

Comment: @Dominique Provided!